# JBoss default password

Tags: jboss

What's the JBoss 5.x EAP default web console password?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The default credentials are:

```
login: admin
password: admin
```

But if you use EAP these credentials are turned off by default and there is no active user (security reasons :)). If you want to turn on these users, you have to edit the following file in your current profile: `./deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/WEB-INF/classes/web-console-users.properties`. It should be enough to remove the `#` sign from the line with the user.

If you want to create a new user, don't forget to set up the correct groups in `web-console-roles.properties` file.

You can easily find information where these information are stored: just open the `./conf/login-config.xml` file and find the proper security domain definition. In the case of the Web Console application, it will be `web-console` policy.

Also if you want to have access to JMX, you have  unlock JMX Console. Just check the following files in  the `conf/props/` directory (in your profile): `jmx-console-users.properties` and `jmx-console-roles.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `./conf/login-config.xml`. I found someone else changed how the accounts were set up - they actually were coming from `conf/props/jmx-console-users.properties` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I just had to uncomment the line in `jboss-eap-5.0\jboss-as\server\default\conf\props\jmx-console-users.properties`

```
admin=admin
```

Thats it. Restart Jboss and I was about to get in to JBOSS JMX. Magically this even fixed the error that I used to get while shutting down Jboss from Eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I can also verify the above solution except I had to change in

```
**..\server\<server profile>\conf\props\jmx-console-users.properties**
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Talend MDM Server, the login is:
login: admin
password: talend

See more: http://wiki.glitchdata.com/index.php?title=TOS:_Accessing_the_Talend_MDM_Server

This differs from the default JBoss login of admin/admin
The password setup file is also login-config.xml  in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
jmx-console-users.properties 
admin=admin
```

Step 2:

```
jmx-console-roles.properties 
admin=JBossAdmin,HttpInvoker
```

Step 3: Restart or start the JBoss instance.

Now you should good to go...

Go to the jmx console, enter JBoss login URL, then enter **admin** as username and **admin** password.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest visit [Add digest auth in jmx-console](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DIGESTAuth) and read oficial documentation for [Configure admin consoles](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Admin_Console_User_Guide/Admin_Console_User_Guide-Configure_the_Admin_Console.html#Adminstration_Console_User_Guide-Configuration-Security-Users_and_Roles), you can add more security to your JBoss AS console and at these link explains where are the role and user/pass files that you need to change this information for your server and how you can change them. Also I recommend you quit all consoles that you don't use because they can affect to application server's performance.
Also there are others links about securing jmx-console that could help you, search in jboss as community site for them (I can't put them here for my actual reputation,sorry). Never you should has the password in plain text over conf/props/ files.

Sorry for my bad English and I hope my answer be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

just commenting the line of user and password in file
./server/default/conf/props jmx-console-users.properties worked for me

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in other posts, probably you don't have any user defined. it's not advisable to manually edit the configuration files. you should use the add-user (.sh or .cmd) utility as explained in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Installation_Guide/chap-Getting_Started_with_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_6.html#Add_the_Initial_User_for_the_Management_Interfaces